# How to kill job by tag Or whatever in laravel horizon?

Tags: laravel, queue, horizon, laravel-horizon

when i dispatch a job for any reason i want to kill that,
how can i do that?

when i restart the supervisor job goes to reserved status, my question is?
When will the tasks in the reserved status be executed by the Worker?

Comment: maybe you could provide more context. what have you done/tried so far?

Comment: flush redis but this bad idea because clear all data, i want terminate specific job